# Is it allowed to use the Spotify Web API for commercial projects?

Tags: spotify, commercial-application

I have a simple question concerning the Spotify Web API.

Is it legal to retrieve data from this service as a base for my app which then should be commercial?

Without going too much into detail: I use the information to present the user an extra service based on this information.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Bye

Comment: You better ask your question here, I think: https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also, you could read https://developer.spotify.com/developer-terms-of-use/

Comment: OK, I'll ask on law.

Comment: The new thread is here: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/15383/is-it-allowed-to-use-the-spotify-web-api-for-commercial-projects

Answer (score 2):

According to https://developer.spotify.com/developer-terms-of-use/#section-iv-restrictions

> commercial uses are not permitted for Streaming SDAs

Reading further,

> following are the only commercial uses of Non-Streaming SDAs
>
> - sale of advertising, sponsorships, or promotions on the Non-Streaming SDA or Website;
> - sale of, or sale of access to, a Non-Streaming SDA (including any e-commerce initiated via the Non-Streaming SDA);

You should better carefully read whole terms of use and consider your use case.

Comment: The new thread is here: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/15383/is-it-allowed-to-use-the-spotify-web-api-for-commercial-projects